# Web2py - how to create popup window?

Tags: python, web2py

What is the preferred way to create a popup window in web2py? For example, let's say you want to pop up a Terms of Service box, and have the user click that he agrees with the terms before allowing the user to proceed - what would be a good way to do this? Is there a way to implement this without javascript, for example, by setting a particular "_target" within "A()" (comparable to how a target of "_blank" can open a new window/tab)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flash (javascript) like this [example #6](http://www.web2py.com/init/default/examples)

If you depend on a pop-up window, almost all browsers are currently blocking them.

If you want the users to accept Terms of Service, put a checkbox in the form besides a "_blank" link to the ToS, and do a simple [postback](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/03#Postbacks) validating that ToS is checked.